# How to convert IL code to Mono.Cecil commands?

Tags: mono.cecil

I have the following C# code

```cs
        this.Succeed = true;
        yield break;
```

which is in IL (says dnSpy):

```
        /* 0x0019AD95 16           */ IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
        /* 0x0019AD96 7380630006   */ IL_0001: newobj    instance void Class893/'<method_0>d__0'::.ctor(int32)
        /* 0x0019AD9B 25           */ IL_0006: dup
        /* 0x0019AD9C 02           */ IL_0007: ldarg.0
        /* 0x0019AD9D 7D54560004   */ IL_0008: stfld     class Class893 Class893/'<method_0>d__0'::'<>4__this'
        /* 0x0019ADA2 2A           */ IL_000D: ret
```

and i want to convert it to Mono.Cecil Instructions like these:

```cs
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0));
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Newobj));
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Dup, 0x0019AD9B));
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldarg_0));
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Stfld, 0x0019AD9D));
                    inst.Add(Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ret));
```

How would i do that?

Comment: You can use this tool too help you learn how to translate C# to Mono.Cecil calls:
https://cecilifier.me/

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this tool

Comment: thank you so much, please write that as answer, i'll gladly accept it

Comment: I've added the information as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://cecilifier.me (https://github.com/adrianoc/cecilifier) tool too help you learn how to translate C# to https://github.com/jbevain/cecil.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of that tool.